# How do I get x-axis to expand to take more of the chart width

Tags: highcharts, gwt-highcharts

As you can see from the attached image, my x-axis categories are getting bunched together in the middle. How can I configure highcharts to take up more of the x-axis? Note: The chart size is dynamic, it grows and shrinks based on the overall browser size and split-panels within the app. So explicit computation of the point-width is not an option (I expect highcharts to do the work for me).

Note: The picture is vertically cropped.

[image]

The chart options I'm using are:

```
highchart.setAnimation(false);
Legend legend = new Legend();
legend.setEnabled(false);
highchart.setLegend(legend);

highchart.getXAxis().setCategories(result.getAxisXCategories().toArray(new String[] {}));
highchart.setType(Series.Type.COLUMN);
ColumnPlotOptions options = new ColumnPlotOptions();
options.setStacking(Stacking.NORMAL);
options.setGroupPadding(0);
options.setAnimation(true);
highchart.setColumnPlotOptions(options);
```

In other words, legend is turned off and column plot options is set to zero group-padding.

UPDATE: Here is a JSFiddle showing the same [issue](http://jsfiddle.net/z4eeP/)

Comment: Can you provide a link to js.fiddle?

Comment: Or post your chart options

Comment: I've added the options I'm setting. I don't have a js.fiddle - this is a gwt-highchart implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who run into the same issue, the solution is to set the pointRange option of the ColumnPlotOptions. In JSON this looks like:

```
"plotOptions": {
        "column": {
            "stacking": "normal",
            pointRange: 1,
                "groupPadding": 0
        }
    }
```

In GWT-Highcharts, you don't actually have a specific API for pointRange. Therefore set a generic option like this:

```
ColumnPlotOptions options = new ColumnPlotOptions();
options.setOption("pointRange", 1.0);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set pointWidth() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

Comment: I'll have to recompute that for every chart resize! To me this looks like broken logic within highchart.

Comment: It looks like a GWT problem, because in Highcharts it looks like fine.  So if it possible could recreate it in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I've updated the question with a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem.